# jQuery - Combining multiple .find() methods and takes elements out of the DOM with .remove()

Tags: jquery

First of all, I was not able to find a similar question. (Overemphasis on I)

*This might be a easy question.* I troed to optimize one of my js files which includes following code.

```
    commentform.find('#comment-status').remove();
    commentform.find('.form-submit .comment-status-ajax-loader').remove();
```

**Question:** Is it possible to combine them? For example like:

```
    commentform.find('#comment-status, .form-submit .comment-status-ajax-loader').remove();
```

Comment: that is exactly how you combine them :-) you answered your question yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Now im happy

Comment: @FlashThunder - does the same works for "var header = $(".navbar-fixed-top");" AND "var header = $(".navbar-logo-wrap");" ?

Comment: not sure what do you mean ...

Comment: I mean can i combine them to `var header = $(".navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-logo-wrap");`

Comment: Yes and no... this will give you array of objects... but if you are using it to `append()`, should work fine. If you are using it with for example `text()`, it won't work... you would have to use `$.each()`

Comment: Ok thx, is there any clear guide on the web to learn these kind of things?

Comment: I guess the best guide is jQuery documentation, but not everything is obvious there...

Comment: "but not everything is obvious there..." i already realized it. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick response from @Flash Thunder it seems, that i answered my own question correctly. Here the solution for all others wich are looking for the same:

```
    commentform.find('#comment-status, .form-submit .comment-status-ajax-loader').remove();
```